# How to a create field which lists the headers of previous fields containing "yes"?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a table in excel of the following format:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║ Field1 ║ Field2 ║ Field3 ║  ...   ║ Field10 ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║   no   ║  no    ║  no    ║  ...   ║  no     ║
║   no   ║  yes   ║  no    ║  ...   ║  no     ║
║   yes  ║  yes   ║  yes   ║  ...   ║  yes    ║
║   yes  ║  yes   ║  no    ║  ...   ║  yes    ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Where as you can see, each field can have any combination of yes's and no's

I am trying to create a single field which is based on the data format previously shown.  This field will contain the name(s) of fields which contained a "yes".  If a "yes" exists in more than one Field, then it should list those fields separated by a comma.

Here is an example of what that desired field might look like:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ Field1 ║ Field2 ║ Field3 ║  ...   ║ Field10 ║         NewField         ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║   no   ║  no    ║  no    ║  ...   ║  no     ║                          ║
║   no   ║  yes   ║  no    ║  ...   ║  no     ║ Field2                   ║
║   yes  ║  yes   ║  yes   ║  ...   ║  yes    ║ Field1, ..., Field10     ║
║   yes  ║  yes   ║  no    ║  ...   ║  yes    ║ Field1, Field2, Field10  ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║ ...                      ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║ ...                      ║
║   .    ║  .     ║  .     ║  ...   ║  .      ║ ...                      ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

I am trying to achieve this with an excel formula, but so far the only solution apparent to me involves including every possible permutation in the excel formula.  Of course, this is inefficient and time-consuming to create and to make changes to.  Is there any way to achieve this result efficiently?

Comment: The only way to do this solely with formulas is if you have the latest Office 365 Excel.  Until February 2016 Excel did not include a formula to do this, without a lot of IF statements.

Comment: @ScottCraner: In that case, do you think that it would be best to look to VBA for solutions?

Comment: Yes,  A custom UDF would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then here is a Custom UDF to do what you want:

```
Function JoinField(ttl As Range, srchrng As Range, crit As Variant, Optional sep As String = ",") As String
Dim ttlArr() As Variant
Dim srchrngArr() As Variant
Dim i&,j&
ttlArr = ttl.Value
srchrngArr = srchrng.Value

If UBound(ttlArr, 1) <> UBound(srchrngArr, 1) Or UBound(ttlArr, 2) <> UBound(srchrngArr, 2) Then Exit Function

For i = LBound(ttlArr, 1) To UBound(ttlArr, 1)
    For j = LBound(ttlArr, 2) To UBound(ttlArr, 2)
        If srchrngArr(i, j) = crit Then
            JoinField = JoinField & ttlArr(i, j) & sep
        End If
    Next j
Next i

JoinField = Left(JoinField, Len(JoinField) - Len(sep))


End Function
```

Put this in a module attached to the workbook.  **DO NOT** put it in the worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code.

It is then called like a normal function:

```
=JoinField($A$1:$J$1,$A2:$J2,"Yes",",")
```

Where the first criteria is the names to concatenate.  The second is the Range that has the criteria.  The third is the Criteria to find.  The forth is optional separation character.  Default is `,`.

[image]

---

If you have the latest Office 365 Excel you can use this formula as an array.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A2:$J2 = "Yes", $A$1:$J$1,""))
```

Being an array it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Is it possible to have this so that if none of the fields have a "yes", then it will leave the cell as null? Otherwise, it gives "####" or "#VALUE!"

Comment: @Paradox just wrap the formula in an IFERROR(): `=IFERROR(JoinField($A$1:$J$1,$A2:$J2,"Yes",","),"")`

Answer (score 1):

As a demonstration of how tedious and verbose the FORMULA would get using multiple IF formulas, you could wind up with a formula looking like the following:

```
=IF(LEFT(IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""),1)=",",SUBSTITUTE(IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""),", ","",1),IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""))
```

The above formula assumed row 1 as your field headers, and your first field starting column A.  The above formula would be placed in K2 and copied down.

Now if for some reason you are not allowed to use VBA or save your your worksheet in and .XLSM format, then you would need something like that hideous formula above.

With out the scroll bar, the formula looks more like:

```
=IF(LEFT(IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&
IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&
IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&
IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""),1)=",",
SUBSTITUTE(IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&
IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&
IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&
IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""),", ","",1),
IF(A2="yes",A$1,"")&IF(B2="yes",", "&B$1,"")&IF(C2="yes",", "&C$1,"")&
IF(D2="yes",", "&D$1,"")&IF(E2="yes",", "&E$1,"")&IF(F2="yes",", "&F$1,"")&
IF(G2="yes",", "&G$1,"")&IF(H2="yes",", "&H$1,"")&IF(I2="yes",", "&I$1,"")&
IF(J2="yes",", "&J$1,""))
```

Proof of ugliness at work

[image: POC]

A major down side of this is that if you needed to add another field the editing of the formula would be a royal pain in the butt!

Answer (score 0):

If theres only 10 Columns you could go with sth. like this

=IF(A2=1;INDIRECT("A1";TRUE);"") & ", " & IF(B2=1;INDIRECT("B1";TRUE);"") & ", " & ....

In this Example a just added 0, 1 as values not the yes/no.

Comment: The Indirects are not needed, also youwill want to put the `,` inside the IF so you do not end up with `Field1,,,Field4...`  I would `MID(IF(A2=1,"," & $A$1,"") & IF(B2=1,"," & $B$1,"") & ...,2,9999)`  with the "," inside the IF we remove them when the title is not included.  We use the mid to get rid of the first `,` and put one one the first one on purpose.  Then is does not matter if the first title is included or not.